# Laravel 5 route strange behavior

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, routes

I have 2 routes:
[image: routes]

```
Route::get('dashboard', 'MainController@dashboard')->name('dashboard');
Route::get('dashboardExtCall/{name}', 'MainController@dashboardExtCall');
```

And their implementation:

```
class MainController extends Controller
{

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth');
    }

    public function dashboardExtCall($name)
    {
        Session::put('activeUrl', $name);
        return $this->dashboard();
    }

    public function dashboard()
    {

        $user = Auth::user();

        //SETTING VARIABLES IN SESSION
        if (!Session::has('activeUrl')) {
            Session::put('activeUrl', 'appList');
        }

        $info = Session::get('info');
        Session::forget('info');

        $creditsNumber = Credits::GetCreditsNumber();
        return view('dashboard\dashboard')->with([
            'user' => $user,
            'creditsNumber' => $creditsNumber,
            'info' => $info,
        ]);
    }
}
```

The problem is that I get the errors 405 and 404 on resources (e.g. images) when I use `dashboardExtCall/userPage`.

If I change this route to this and call `dashboardExtCall` - everything works fine!

```
Route::get('dashboardExtCall', 'MainController@dashboardExtCall');
/******************/
public function dashboardExtCall(){    
  Session::put('activeUrl', 'userPage');
  return $this->dashboard();
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Use post call in route

Comment: Check your templates and be sure that you're using the [public_path helper](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/helpers#paths) or using absolute paths to your resources

Comment: @SachinAghera, I can't use POST, because I need to call it from external resource (e.g. email)

Comment: public function dashboardExtCall(Request $request){    
  Session::put('activeUrl', $request->name);
  return $this->dashboard();
}

Comment: Not clear: what is your issue with resources?

Comment: if you got 405 http error, it is `method not allowed` and you are not using `GET` method, how do you request the uri?